# How to write following code in Kotlin for callback implementation

Tags: java, android, interface, callback

---

> how do i write in Kotlin like java?

---

```
Callback callback= new Callback()
 {
     @Override
     public void getCallback(ServerResponse serverResponse) {

     }
 }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use following code in Kotlin.

```
var callback:Callback = object:Callback() {
  fun getCallback(serverResponse:ServerResponse) {
  }
}
```

You can use this link to convert your Java code to kotlin.
https://try.kotlinlang.org

Comment: var callback:CallBack = object:CallBack {
        override fun callBackFun(obj: Any, function: () -> Unit) {
           
        }
    }

Answer (score 12):

```
var callback:Callback = object:Callback() {
  override fun getCallback(serverResponse:ServerResponse) {
  }
}
```

`var callback:Callback` says that the variable type is a `Callback`

`object:Callback() { }` is an anonymous class. It has no name when created, before being assigned to `var callback`. It's similar to the `new Callback()` code.

`override`  replaces @Override

`fun` indicates that it is a function

Comment: I think it's not an anonymous function, rather it's an anonymous class, which implements the `Callback` interface. Actually the overridden function `getCallback` has a name, 'getCallback', which is not anonymous.